# SSIS file started by SQL Server Agent fails (Source SQLISPackage120, Event ID: 12291)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

I have SSIS file *.dtx which works on test machine with test sql server and works locally started with production/test sql server. When the file is moved to production machine and started with production machine (no change of credection in SSIS file) it fails with message in event log: `Source SQLISPackage120, Event ID: 12291`.

The logging is turned on: with works everywhere except production machine. It logs also when SSIS file is started locally from VS but with production database.

How to find more information about problem?

UPDATE1:

I found in SQL Agent log file entry:

Login failed for user 'aaa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ...]

How to configure windows user to be able to run SSIS task (or to be able to log in SQL server from SSIS)?

Comment: Post the error messages. It's impossible to help otherwise. Most likely you forgot to change the connection strings, folders or credentials to those appropriate for production. Right-click on your pagage and go to the "Reports > Standard> All Executions" report and check the errors

Comment: Where is that "Reports > Standard> All Executions" ? Which app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that user defined in SSIS's connection string had no access to production's database called XXX.

The most important information were found in SQL Server log file:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\errorlog